# How to resolve jQuery libraries conflict in project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magento2, conflict

I am facing a small problem while using Bootstrap Carousel. Actually 
my project is in Magneto 2, and is using jQuery 1.12.4 but the Bootstrap Carousel wants 3.2.1 version of jQuery.

How can I resolve this conflict?

Right now, the scenario is Bootstrap Carousel is working fine in standalone example but when I try to use in my Magneto 2 project, it is not working.

I followed [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h) of carousel.

Answer (score 0):

If the page in which you want to use carousel does not require jQuery v 1.12.4 then load v 3.2.1 in that particular page. Or if the older jquery is being included by master template then load the new JQ in the page again in such a way that it loads after older JQ.

So it will override older JQ file with new one for that particular page. And you will be good to go with Carousel.

Try this out and do comment how it goes.

Comment: Thats  make sense Thanks a lot but Sir  thats what i  exactly tried and my header-Nav is stop working (Only on this)

Comment: Can you try to remove the `<script>` tag which loads old JQ file while the page is getting loaded? I believe header-nav should work with new JQ too because with each update in JQ version, older functions would be maitained. Give it a try.

Comment: Can you elaborate remove the <script>  
IF i remove  scrpit tag then how can i add old jq

Comment: For the page where the carousel is, just write jquery to remove `<script>` so it won't get loaded. And check if header-nav works with (only) new one or not.